# Text Parse Exception when Converting Gson response in Android

Tags: android, gson, response, typetoken

Hi I have problem with converting json response to my object when change device language!!! actually it is correct when my device set on english language but when i change the device language (for example to persian),i have exception!!!
Please help me
Excuse me for my bad writing !
Thanks!:)

```
    AsyncTask<String, String, String> p = new PostService(context, url,
            object, new ServiceCallback() {

                public void onTaskComplete(String response) {

                            List<ClassName> objectList = gson.fromJson(response,
                                    new TypeToken<List<ClassName>>() {
                                   }.getType());

                 }

            }).execute();
```

And exception is as follows ,

```
com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Mar 29, 2015" (at offset 0)
```

Comment: Please show your exception

Comment: com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Mar 29, 2015" (at offset 0)

Comment: post your json response please

Comment: Eception: com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Mar 29, 2015" (at offset 0)
at com.google.gson.internal.bind.SqlDateTypeAdapter.read(SqlDateTypeAdapter.java:59)
at com.google.gson.internal.bind.SqlDateTypeAdapter.read(SqlDateTypeAdapter.java:38)